# Not able to select the third element in dropdown list

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a header file which is used to contain header of my web page. This header file is included in every page.Drpdown list mentioned in this header file displaying the menu but not able to clcik after 2nd element. I have the following code for the dropdown list. This code is working fine in [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gLwn729z/1/) but in my web page it is not working. I am not able to select "Region3" and 2nd child of "Region2"(Manage Region). The moment i try to place my cursor or the third element it disappears from the screen.

What is the problem?

```css
    .parent {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        float: right;
        line-height: 50px;
        background-color: #a9cc77;
        border-right: #CCC 1px solid;
    }
    
    .parent a {
        margin: 10px;
        color: #000;
        text-decoration: none;
        Font-weight:bold;
    }
    
    .parent:hover>ul {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
    }
    
    .child {
        display: none;
    }
    
    .child li {
        background-color: #E4EFF7;
        line-height: 30px;
        border-bottom: #CCC 1px solid;
        border-right: #CCC 1px solid;
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    .child li a {
        color: #000000;
    }
    
    ul {
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0px;
        min-width: 10em;
    }
    
    ul ul ul {
        left: 100%;
        top: 0;
        margin-left: 1px;
    }
    
    li:hover {
        background-color:#04ba0d;
    }
    
    .parent li:hover {
        background-color: #14871a;
    }
    
    .expand {
        font-size: 12px;
        float: right;
        margin-right: 5px;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse set-radius-zero" >
    <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <h1 class="coolShadow" STYLE="margin-left:145px;font-weight:BOLD;text-align:center;" >SYSTEM</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="right-div" style="padding:25px 0px 5px 0px;">
    <a href="logout.php" class="btn btn-danger pull-right" style="margin-right:0px;">LOG ME OUT</a>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <!-- LOGO HEADER END-->
    <section class="menu-section">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row ">
    <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse ">
    <ul id="menu">
    <li class="parent"><a href="change-password.php">Change Password</a></li>
    <li class="parent"><a href="#">Configuration<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
    <ul class="child">
    <li class="parent"><a href="#">Region1 <span class="expand">»</span></a>
    <ul class="child">
    <li><a href="add-region.php">Add Region</a></li>
    <li><a href="manage-region.php">Manage Region</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="parent"><a href="#">Region2 <span class="expand">»</span></a>
    <ul class="child">
    <li><a href="add-region.php">Add Region</a></li>
    <li><a href="manage-region.php">Manage Region</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="parent"><a href="#">Region3 <span class="expand">»</span></a>
    <ul class="child">
    <li><a href="add-region.php">Add Region</a></li>
    <li><a href="manage-region.php">Manage Region</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="parent"><a href="dashboard.php">Home</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: This all works just fine for me in both Firefox and Chrome.  What browser/device are you on?  Are there other details you can provide?

Comment: @Jake This file is saved as header file for my website .But when i include this header file in other pages it does not work .The problem is that menu item can not displayed beyond the page .

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that I am importing this file to another webpage and the dropdown menu was not expanding beyond the its container.by keeping the z index property the problem resolved.Add css property `z-index: 9999999` to the parent and problem resolved.